# Channel binding when connecting in Java to LDAP server - is it possible?

Tags: java, windows, ldap

Microsoft has new patch with LDAP connection.
Servers with this patch will not accept connections with no 'channel binding'
My code connects today with 'InitialLdapContext'.
I'm preparing the env and create a new InitialLdapContext.
LDAP/LDAPs working fine.
After this patch,
Will servers reject LDAPs connection?
Will I have to add channel binding handling?
I don't see that InitialLdapContext has channel binding handling.

Comment: What is the eqvivalent parameter to send in order to match the Windows server configuration?

If the server is configured with 'LdapEnforceChannelBinding = 1 (When Supported) or 2 (Always)

I've configured the 'java.naming.security.authentication' as 'strong' but the authentication fails.

If I send 'java.naming.security.authentication' as 'simple', the authentication succeeds even if the server was configured with 1 (When Supported) or 2 (Always)

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4520412/2020-ldap-channel-binding-and-ldap-signing-requirements-for-windows